# MongoDB: Query by 2 arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have schema as follows:

```
Course:
      id,
      [ User ],
      [ Subscriber]
```

Each user has userId and each subscriber has a subscriber id.

Now, I am given two arrays for userIds and subscriberIds.
Example:

**These Ids are ObjectIds and not strings.**

UserIds: [1,2,3] and subscriberIds: [4,2,6]

Now I need to find 3 courses having userIds and subscriberIds as (1,4) ; (2,2) ; (3,6)

So, here we don't want a cross product.

Comment: I tried concatenating the userId and subscriberId, but we cannot concatenate two objectIds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.find({
  $or: userIds.map((userId, index) => ({
    User: userId,
    Subscriber: subscriberIds[index]
  }))
}).limit(3)
```